# Cannot access data in active record using dot notation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created a model in Ruby and am stuck on a n00b issue. In Rails Console:

> > s = Survey.where(:keyword => 'foo')
> >     => [#]
> >     s.inittxtmsg
> >     NoMethodError: undefined method `inittxtmsg' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x10350f8f8>
> >         from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.5/lib/active_record/relation.rb:371:in`method_missing'
> >         from (irb):3

Shouldn't I be able to see the values by typing s.Survey_id, s.inittxtmsg, s.keyword, s.store?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Survey.where(:keyword => 'foo')
```

returns an array of results, so you are really calling .inittxtmsg on an array, which obviously doesn't exist.

You  could do something like:

`Survey.where(:keyword => 'foo').first.inittxtmsg`, in which it is calling it on the actual model object.

Or if you know that there is only one survey with the keyword = foo... you can use the find method to only return a single model object:

```
s = Survery.find_by_keyword("foo")
s.inittxtmsg
```

Comment: `s = Survery.find(:keyword => "foo")` won't work. You should use `s = Survery.find_by_keyword("foo")`

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem myself by putting .first at the end, but probably will switch to find_by_keyword.